# Is the $n$-th order derivative the derivative of the $n-1$-th order one?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#The_total_derivative.2C_the_total_differential_and_the_Jacobian):

> **The natural analog of second, third, and higher-order total derivatives** is not a linear transformation, is not a function on the
>   tangent bundle, and **is not built by repeatedly taking the total
>   derivative**.

I think the $n$-th order (total) derivative of a mapping is the derivative of its $n-1$-th order derivative. In other words, derivative can be defined recursively. So I was wondering how to understand that "the natural analog of second, third, and higher-order total derivatives ... is not built by repeatedly taking the total derivative"?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I just thought the same thing about that Wikipedia article. As it is it looks plain wrong and Didier's answer below corroborates this.

Answer (score 1):

As explained on the WP page, if $f:E\to F$ for finite dimensional vector spaces $E$ and $F$, then $f':E\to V$ where $V=L(E,F)$ is the space of linear maps from $E$ to $F$. Hence $f'':E\to W$ where $W=L(E,V)$ is the space of linear maps from $E$ to $V$, and so on.

In general, the vector spaces $V$, $W$ and their analogues for higher derivatives are all different, for example if $E$ and $F$ have dimensions $n$ and $m$, the dimension of $V$ is $nm$, the dimension of $W$ is $n^2m$, and so on, hence the objects $f'$, $f''$ and so on, are each in a different space. However, when $E=\mathbb R$, then  for every finite dimensional vector space $U$ there is a natural identification of $L(E,U)=U^*$ with $U$ since every $\varphi$ in $L(\mathbb R,U)$ is $\varphi:x\mapsto xu$ for a given $u$ in $U$.

Using these identifications, when $E=\mathbb R$ and $F$ is finite dimensional, for each $n\geqslant1$, $f^{(n)}$ corresponds to a function from $\mathbb R$ to $L(\mathbb R,F)=F^*\simeq F$.

Comment: Thanks! (1) "f(n) corresponds to a function from R to F", probably you wanted to say "f(n) corresponds to a function from R to U"? (2) So the n-th order derivative is defined as the derivative of the (n-1)-th order derivative, isn't it?

Comment: (3) Isn't derivative defined at least for mappings between Banach spaces, instead of between general vector spaces?